# How to recall constructor or ngOnInit after second click over link?

Tags: angular

When I do the second click by the same route link a component is not reloaded.

How to recall constructor or `ngOnInit` after second click over link?

Comment: Use ngOnChanges for this.

Comment: please provide the code with a link, router config and the actual component

Comment: By default the router wont creaate a new instance of the component https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit will never be called twice. It only call when the component is create, if the component is already create, you can use `ngOnChanges()`, which is call once when the component is create, and every time that properties changes. See [LifeCycle Hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for more

Comment: When works `ngOnChanges`. It does not show me changes after clicking the same link